# Make object not have effect on ambient occlusion

Tags: materials, particles, eevee-render-engine

So here is my problem, i have a  displaced plane textured with a material that uses ambient occlusion in it in the form of the ambient occlusion node as a factor in a colorramp, for simplicities sake, i'll say my material is just the colorramp and ambient occlusion plugged into the material output. now i want to use a particle system to spread an object across the surface (let's say a cube). but when i do that the material becomes very dark since the particles effect the ambient occlusion. is there any way i could make the particle (cube) not have any effect on the ambient occlusion? i don't want to have to lower the distance or effect of the AO, i'd like for the cube to have zero effect on the AO.
Thanks in advance!
EDIT: using eevee

Comment: Does the 'Only Local' checkbox in the node do that for you?

Comment: no, unfortunately not. i'm using eevee btw, should have specified.